# How are 3rd party dll's referenced on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a simple webapi solution (aspnet core 2.1) consisting of two projects, Test.api (containing a controller) and Test.Models. The Models project has Newtosoft package and uses JsonIgnore attribute on models. When I deploy this solution to Azure app service and view the contents of the deployed folder via cloud explorer (also used kudu), I don't see the Newtosoft dll.

Where is it being referenced from? Does app service have an equivalent of GAC?

Comment: Yes, it's a Windows Server 2016 box with a special sandbox and .NET Framework 4.7. It behaves accordingly - `cd %systemroot%\assembly && dir`

Comment: @evilSnobu After .Net Framework 4.0 all the GAC reference would be pointing towards new directory `cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\ ` also I couldn't see any reference that related to `newtonsoft` in that directory !

Comment: How can you cd (or rdp) into an app service host machine? On my local machine, I see the newtonsoft dll under C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder. This was presumably installed when I installed .Net Core sdk.

Comment: Oh my bad, i failed to see the .NET Core mention. I don't know how the GAC works for .NET Core but it should reflect a regular Windows system. Just `dir /a /s newtonsoft*.dll` from root of D drive in Kudu. **@Red**, [see this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).

Comment: Thanks. Can see the newtonsoft dll on the machine.

Comment: @evilSnobu You could add an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the GAC works for .NET Core but it should reflect a regular Windows system, in essence that's what App Service with Windows workers is, Windows Server + special sandbox.

Just `dir /a /s newtonsoft*.dll` from root of D drive in [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) and it should point you to the DLL in GAC.